# Changing the type of Nth colum elements from List

Tags: r, list, casting, typecasting-operator

This is what I came on. Supposedly, the list[[ ]] would mean all the data.frames from the list, which it did not work.

```
list <- as.Date(list[[]][,2])
```

Not working, tried something as this

```
list <- lapply(list[,2], as.Date)
```

Again an error.

So, that being said, and shown, how can explicit in R languages, that I want to apply the function in all the elements of a column, for all the data.frames of the list, in the best way

Comment: do you want a new data with the dates of each list or you want to declare the column 2 in all the elements of the list `as.Date`?

Comment: I just want to declare it as dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do want you want with any of the `apply` functions but a simple loop works

```
data1 = data.frame(y = seq(1,10),x=seq(from = 1789,to = 2789,length.out=10))
data2 = data.frame(y = seq(11,20),x=seq(from = 1789,to = 2789,length.out=10))
test = list(data1,data2)
for(i in 1:length(test)){
  test[[i]][,2] = as.Date(test[[i]][,2],origin = "1899-12-30")
}
```

In this case I want to convert numeric excel dates in dates in R. 
I tried modifying your second option to:
`lapply(test,function(x) as.Date(x[,2],origin = "1899-12-30"))`
but you would end up only with dates

Comment: You can do `lapply(test,function(x) {x[,2] <- as.Date(x[,2],origin = "1899-12-30"); x})` and you will get back the data frame

Comment: The way you used the function inside the `lapply` didn't know it was possible thats awesome thanks